# How do I get Apache 2.2.17 started?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf

I am running Apache 2.2.17 on Fedora v14. I cannot access the running web server from a browser, and I also have difficulties setting it up to listen on port 443.

The server `httpd` is running:

```
[me@host ~]$ sudo ps -U root -u root u | grep httpd
root      6592  0.0  3.4 404620 17552 ?        Ss   10:50   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k graceful
```

I then stop the service:

```
[me@host ~]$ sudo apachectl stop
```

I then set up the `Listen` directive in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to listen on ports 80 and 443:

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:80
Listen 1.2.3.4:443 https
```

(The IP is not `1.2.3.4` but the actual IP of this host.)

I checked the other Apache conf directives to make sure I have a document folder, that it is accessible by all users, and that it will show a directory listing of the folder, if I do not specify `index.html` etc.

When attempting to start `httpd`, I get a configuration error:

```
[me@host conf]$ sudo apachectl graceful
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

No other services appear to be running on TCP port 443 (or port 80):

```
[me@host conf]$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 443
[me@host conf]$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80
```

If I comment out the 443 `Listen` directive and `graceful`-restart the `httpd` service, it starts and is visible in the process list (via `ps`, as above) but I am still unable to access the host via web browser.

Is there anything I have overlooked in setting up Apache? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check iptables rules:

```
iptables -nv -L
```

To add new rules, edit /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
...
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
...
```

To restart iptables:

```
#service iptables restart
```

To stop iptables:

```
#service iptables stop
```

For debug use tcpdump:

```
# tcpdump -pn host YOU_IP and not port 22
or
# tcpdump -pn port 443 and icmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I just commented the line

```
Listen *:80
```

and now it is working.

Before doing this, run the command `hostname` and add this name to your `/etc/hosts`. In `httpd.conf` I have the same name on the line `ServerName`.

I controlled before that no service was using this port :80 in my case.